# React App: Why I get an error when I try to run npm start script?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I installed all required packages and trying to run `npm start` script which gives me the error below:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:118:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Alex\Practise\React website\front-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Here's copy of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to delete and reinstall the whole project, reinstall node and packages with no luck.
Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upgrade your `react-scripts` to `3.4.0`. I've just installed modules provided from your `package.json` and upgraded `react-scripts` to the newest version and everything works fine.

More details on [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8490#issuecomment-586556584).

Comment: I followed this advice and changed 3.3.0 to 3.4.0. Then deleted `node_modules` and did `npm install`

Comment: What is the React App is ejected?