# npm start throws an error when trying to run on a new unit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

My computer got damaged, so I'm using a different unit I had lying down. I've installed node.js, then opened my project and ran both `npm i react-scripts` and also just `npm install` to just install all of my project's dendancies.

But when I run `npm start` I keep getting an error I don't understand. This is the log:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Assaf Tzabary\Documents\coding\name-generator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

This unit was never used for any type of coding before so I wonder maybe there's something I should install but haven't? I can't tell what that might be.

It saya it has something to do with the router? But I see the router packages are installed in my `node modules`.

Comment: Would you mind posting the block of code where the error is happening?

Comment: It doesn't point to anywhere specific in my code, just to node modules / libraries I think. And this is the only error I get in the browser when trying to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React App: Why I get an error when I try to run npm start script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243820/react-app-why-i-get-an-error-when-i-try-to-run-npm-start-script)